# Doubles substraction in Java

Tags: java, math, double, bigdecimal

I am trying to make some calculus in Java related to entropies and information gain and I use a formula that looks like this: info_gain = infogain - nr1 / nr2 * nr3.

nr1, nr2, nr3 and infogain are doubles.

The problem is that the result from nr1 / nr2 * nr3 is corect. But when I do the subtraction I get some ugly results.

For example nr1 / nr2 * nr3 is 0.574716 and the initial value of the infogain is 0.575306.
When I do the substraction I get 0.000589.
That's not correct or is not what is supposed to return (I did the calculus on paper).

I tried to use BigDecimal using MathContext.DECIMAL64 and for divide(nr, 10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).

So, is there any posibility to get the result from above 0.001? (or something similar, but not 0.000589).

Comment: The answer `0.00059` is correct, you probably did something wrong on paper...

Comment: If the subtraction doesn't produce the expected result although one of the operands is correct, I would assume that the other operand is not what you think it is or that the expected result is not correct, rather than thinking that your computer can't subtract numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhh, 0.575306 - 0.574716 is in fact 0.00059.

[image]

Comment: Love that you typed that into WolframAlpha. The Mathematica engine is reduced to solving people's inability to subtract.

Comment: Just making sure I'm posting the correct result, haha!